# OpenEdge 10.2A - Is it possible to displaying DOS Characters (Chr(219) █ ) on Windows in a browse?

Tags: character-encoding, openedge, progress-4gl

In some of our browses, we want to use old dos character chr(219) █ in order to create a field like a progress bar or a bar-chart.

Our codes and database use codepage-1254.

## Setting I

We have tried to create field value as:

```
myTable.myValue=fill(chr(219,"IBM857","1254"),100).
```

Also we have used startup parameters as:

```
-cpinternal IBM857
```

and result is:

```
ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ
```

## Setting II

We have tried to create field value as:

```
myTable.myValue=fill(chr(219,"IBM857","1254"),100).
```

Also we have used startup parameters as:

```
-cprcodein 1254 -cpinternal IBM857
```

and result is:

```
ÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛÛ
```

## Setting III

We have tried to create field value as:

```
myTable.myValue=fill(chr(219,"IBM857","1254"),100).
```

Also we have used startup parameters as:

```
-cprcodein 1254
```

and result is:

```
êêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêê
```

## Setting IV

We have tried to create field value as:

```
myTable.myValue=fill(chr(219,"IBM857"),100).
```

Also we have used startup parameters as:

```
-cpinternal IBM857
```

and result is:
    ››››››››››››››››››››››››››››››››››

## Setting V

We have tried to create field value as:

```
myTable.myValue=fill(chr(219,"IBM857"),100).
```

Also we have used startup parameters as:

```
-cprcodein 1254 -cpinternal IBM857
```

and result is:
    ››››››››››››››››››››››››››››››››››

## Setting VI

We have tried to create field value as:

```
myTable.myValue=fill(chr(219,"IBM857")),100).
```

Also we have used startup parameters as:

```
-cprcodein 1254
```

and result is:
    êêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêêê

#### As a result,

we want to produce an output as follows:

██████████████████████████████████████

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1254 is Turkish and does not contain a character like the one that you are trying to display.

You might try setting -cpterm but I believe that only applies to character terminal output (_progres.exe) so it probably will not help you with a Windows GUI (_prowin.exe) program.

Another possiblity is -cpstream and defining your display FRAME with stream-io.

Otherwise I think your best option is to convert the database to UTF-8 and use the characters available in that environment.  That is also certainly a much more robust solution for the long term.

Comment: I had thought that since IBM857 charset had seemed to have dos characters in it, I would have been able to use some parameters to show them. Unfortunately I could not do it. As a solution, I have created my own font :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to create progress bars or bar charts, I would recommend to use rectangles.
You can create them dynamically, set their look, position & size on the fly, etc.
You can also create vertical bars, which you would not be able to obtain with fill-ins.
See CREATE RECTANGLE hRectangle ASSIGN...

In the past I've done progress bars with pipes (not needing to find any strange character), using a bold font so that the result is not too bad, something like **||||||||||||**

Comment: I do use rectangles to produce progress bars, but I need to show the bar within a browse field. I 've tried pipe character(|) but it does not seem nice enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If those characters are only needed for display, you might get by with leaving the database and -cprcodein at their current values and only set -cpinternal to UTF-8.
Some rework might be required for the application, depending on how cleanly it is written.

Comment: When I use -cpinternal with UTF-8, it produces "Collation table for code page UTF-8 and collation name TURKISH was not found in convmap.cp. (1043)" error.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to show dos characters using -cpinternal, - cprcodein etc.,  as a work-around, I have created a new font and changed some unused characters for the specific field (i.e. ` | ^ ) to different thickness of █ in order to use for different cases.[image: this is the result]